# How to encode and decode a const char *

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, serialization

This is the first time for me to try to serialize/deserialize an object.  One member of the object is a type of const char *.

----------------------------------------**Added info here**----------------------------------

This const char * is a byte array that represents an image.  Because of image recognition requirements, I really need to get the values to the UI and back from the UI and store it as a byte array.  I hope this clears up some confusion.

-------------------------------------------**Ended here**-------------------------------------

I am completely baffled by the options I have for both decoding and encoding.  I cannot make sense out of which option to use and the only one that makes sense is asking for an at:(const void *)array.  What goes there?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
```

Below is the line that I cannot figure out.  I have the first two parameters alright but what is the third one?  The parameter for at: is an array.  But I don't have an array.  Am I supposed to be decoding these to an array?  If so, then I need to initialize an array to put the chars into?

```
        _templateData = [decoder decodeArrayOfObjCType:_templateData count:_templateSize at:<#(void *)#>]; //const char *templateData;
```

After that it seems OK:

```
        _templateSize = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"templateSize"];       //NSUInteger templateSize;
        _templateQuality = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"templateQuality"];     //int templateQuality;
        _templateLocation = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"templateLocation"];   //int templateLocation;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And then there is encoding it.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
```

Same problem here.  I don't have an array.  Do I need to initialize an array to put the chars into?  Is that how this line is supposed to work?

```
    [coder encodeArrayOfObjCType:_templateData count:_templateSize at:<#(const void *)#>]
```

The rest appears OK, again:

```
    [coder encodeInteger:_templateSize forKey:@"templateSize"];
    [coder encodeInt:_templateQuality forKey:@"templateQuality"];
    [coder encodeInt:_templateLocation forKey:@"templateLocation"];

}
```

Has anyone out there successfully encoded and decoded a type that is a const char *?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Turn it into an NSString

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and C?

Comment: Because I have Objective-C talking to Objective-C++ and then to C++.

Comment: @CharlieBurns - My const char array is really an image.  I don't know what kind of encoding to use for that conversion.

Comment: Ah, use NSData as shown below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the best solution is to turn your array of data into an NSData instance, and encode that. It's pretty straightforward:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:_templateData length:lengthOfTemplateData freeWhenDone:NO];
[coder encodeObject:data forKey:@"templateData"];
```

Then, for decoding:

```
NSData *data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"templateData"];
[data getBytes:_templateData length:sizeOfTemplateDataBuffer]; // Assumes _templateData has been allocated to hold sizeOfTemplateDataBuffer bytes.
```

Comment: For encoding consider: `+ (id)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length`

Comment: NSData *data = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"templateData"];
[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:(__bridge void *)(data) length:_templateSize];

Comment: OK.  I have encoders and decoders in place.  I'll mark this question as answered and open another if I have any trouble getting the values on the other side.  Thanks, guys!!!!  :-)

Comment: @Zaph, good advice, although an NSData instance created with that method will free the passed in buffer when it is deallocated, which is probably not desired. I updated my answer to avoid copying the buffer but also to avoid inappropriately freeing it.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - [data getBytes:_templateData length:_templateSize]; gives me a warning "Sending 'const char *' to parameter of type 'void *' discards qualifiers"

Comment: You need to cast the pointer to a `void *`: `[data getBytes:(void *)_templateData length:_templateSize];`